# generating multidimensional object with array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I am generating an object like this:

[image: console snapshot]

As you can see `education` is an array inside an object,
but what I want is for `degree_1` and `major_1` and their values to be in the same object.

This is how I want it but with `education` as an array:
[image]

One other thing: 
When I var_dump it in my php it is just fine with the arrays and everything. But my javascript gets the second image above- object of object when it was just an array..

```
public function show($id)
{
    $tmp = array();
    $post = array();
    $postInfo = Post::find($id);
    $params =  DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT param.*, sys_param_values.*,param_value.*,type_post.*,
                                       param.name AS paramName, 
                                       doc_param.name AS docParamName 
                                       FROM param
                                       LEFT JOIN doc_param ON param.doc_param_id = doc_param.id
                                       LEFT JOIN sys_param_values ON param.id = sys_param_values.param_id
                                       LEFT JOIN param_value ON sys_param_values.value_ref = param_value.id
                                       LEFT JOIN type_post ON sys_param_values.ref_id = type_post.id WHERE type_post.id = ".$id));

    $isMultiple = false;
    $post['postInfo'] = $postInfo['original'];
    foreach($params as $k=>$v) {

        $iteration    = $v->iteration;
        $docParamName = $v->docParamName;
        $paramName    = $v->paramName;

        if($v->value_ref == null) {
            $value = $v->value_short;
        } else {
            $value = $v->value;
        }

        if($iteration) {

            $post[$docParamName][$iteration][$paramName] = $value;
            // need to return education as array not as object
            // $post[$docParamName][] = array($paramName=>$value) ;

        }elseif(!$iteration) {
            $post[$docParamName][$paramName] = $value;
        }
    }   

    return Response::json($post);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your PHP code too, please?

Comment: How do you generate it now? What have you tried so far?

Comment: maybe make first element from `education` to 0, now is 1, so that's why json_encode could parse it as object.

Comment: Actually `education` is an array of objects. **Show the code that builds `education`** Edit your question, dont add it as a comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes it is but when i get it in my client side it returns as the second picture

Comment: @Skamielina yes you right. i will try to see if i can use it like that.

Comment: @Skamielina please post this as an answer, it was a lifesaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make first element from `education` to 0, now it is 1, so that's why json_encode is parsing it as an object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you data source looks like, but it looks to me that you're fetching vertical data and them want to display it horizontally. If that is the case your data need to be stored in a way that simply looping is enough, if not some PHP logic will be required.

We can't really help you on that until you show us an example of your table contents.

Cheers

Comment: I think you have a good point. Show us the output from your query at least the result rows related to the `education` data you are returning